# How can i union two pd.Series efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, performance, optimization, series

I have two *sorted* `pd.Series` like

```
A = [1, 3, 5, 7]
B = [3, 4, 5, 8, 10]
```

I'd like to union them to get a new **list**

```
C = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]
```

The following code can solve it.

```
A = pd.Series([1, 3, 5, 7], name='col')
B = pd.Series([3, 4, 5, 8, 10], name='col')
pd.concat([A,B], axis=0).drop_duplicates().sort_values(ascending=True)
```

Or alternatively I can do

```
list(set(A).union(set(B))).sort()
```

My real problem has very huge arrays, and each of A1, A2, A3, A50 has *100k+* strings. And **more than 99% elements are overlapping.** The union operation will run 50 times.

Which solution is more time efficient? Do we have a even more efficient way to union them w/o using `Cython` or `numba`?

Comment: Strings work differently than numbers in Pandas where an element in a Series is actually a pointer to a Python object, so IIRC, you won't see any performance improvements from using Pandas over plain Python.

Comment: FWIW, you can cut out one step by doing `.union(B)`.

Comment: Minor thing, but `.sort()` doesn't return anything so there's no output from the second snippet.

Comment: Are `A` and `B` already sorted? Sorted arrays can be merged very quickly. For example, you could use [sortednp](https://pypi.org/project/sortednp/).

Comment: @ken Yes. The input arrays are sorted. I've updated the OP.

Comment: `sortednp` is quite efficient but unfortunately doesn't work on strings, I added some extra timings about it in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set operation might be quite efficient, faster if you first convert to lists:

```
sorted(set(A.tolist()).union(B.tolist()))
```

Let's do some timings and add [`numpy.union1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.union1d.html) in the comparison:

```
# 100k+ strings. And more than 99% elements are overlapping
A = pd.Series(map(str, range(100_000))).sample(frac=1)
B = pd.Series(map(str, range(1000, 101_000))).sample(frac=1)

%%timeit
sorted(set(A).union(B))
# 107 ms ± 4.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
sorted(set(A.tolist()).union(B.tolist()))
# 71 ms ± 4.61 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
np.union1d(A, B).tolist()
# 189 ms ± 22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
pd.concat([A,B], axis=0).drop_duplicates().sort_values(ascending=True).tolist()
# 152 ms ± 5.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Timings if the inputs are already sorted:

```
# set union
64.5 ms ± 2.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# set union from lists
51.9 ms ± 2.29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# numpy.union1d
134 ms ± 2.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

###### alternative: [`sortednp`](https://pypi.org/project/sortednp/)

This alternative was mentioned as comment, it is indeed very efficient **if you have numeric data**, but unfortunately won't work with strings.

```
import sortednp as snp

A = pd.Series(range(100_000))
B = pd.Series(range(1000, 101_000))

out = snp.merge(A.to_numpy(), B.to_numpy(), duplicates=snp.DROP).tolist()
```

Timing with numbers:

```
%timeit snp.merge(A.to_numpy(), B.to_numpy(), duplicates=snp.DROP)
# 552 µs ± 4.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit snp.merge(A.to_numpy(), B.to_numpy(), duplicates=snp.DROP).tolist()
# 1.7 ms ± 149 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit sorted(set(A).union(B))
# 17 ms ± 1.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit sorted(set(A.tolist()).union(B.tolist()))
# 13.6 ms ± 2.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np.union1d(A, B).tolist()
# 9.8 ms ± 239 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit pd.concat([A,B], axis=0).drop_duplicates().sort_values(ascending=True).tolist()
# 4.99 ms ± 271 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```